# Pop double from text file

Tags: java

I'd like to pop from text file which looks like "70.869, 78.22, 368.12...". I wrote this code using delimiters but it doesn't work for `double` ( my console after compile project is empty ). If I change it to `int` it works perfectly fine. I'd like to put this numbers to the array.

```
 Scanner src = new Scanner(new File("ala1.txt"));
 src.useDelimiter(", *");
 float [] taller = new float [15];
 int k = 0;

 // Read and sum numbers.
 while(src.hasNextDouble()){
    //tall[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(src.nextDouble());
 }
 src.close();
```

Comment: Does your file have only one line?

Answer (score 3):

Your delimiter looks fine, which suggests that problem is somewhere else.

From your question it looks like `hasNextDouble` doesn't see `70.869` as proper double. Possible problem could be that your locales instead of `.` expects `,` in double value (and based on your code it looks like your locale is Polish which confirms this theory).
So if that is the case make your Scanner use other locale which expects `.` in double instead of `,` like `Locale.ENGLISH`:

```
Scanner src = new Scanner("70.869, 78.22, 368.12");
src.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
src.useDelimiter(", *");
while(src.hasNextDouble()){
   System.out.println(src.nextDouble());
}
```

Output:

```
70.869
78.22
368.12
```